How risky is it not to replace the checksum function when copying data between S3 buckets via the AWS web console?
When copying data between S3 buckets via the AWS web console, one may replace the default checksum function:

How risky is it not to replace the checksum function when copying data between S3 buckets via the AWS web console?

did you used the learn. more functions that are provided?

Reddit user coinclink gave the following answer, which was heavily upvoted (17 points in 1 day):

The only reason it's there is for organizations with regulatory requirements to use a specific checksum function. Unless you have a documented compliance reason, you don't need to ever change it.

